# cannot pass value from one html to another html page using href

Tags: html, arrays

i cannot pass my value from one html page to another html using href link. please help to suggest is there any way i can do to get the link ? following is my code:
page1 html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Node.js app</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="b.html?value=$1" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

page2 html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
      <script>
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
          const PayValue = urlParams.get('value');
          console.log(PayValue);
    </script>
      <h1>this is second page value:PayValue</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your problem? passing value through query string? reading the query string value? showing the query string on the page?

Comment: Hi Saeed, i want to show query string on page

Comment: You code seem to be working as intended. When using `?value=$1` the value `$1` will appear in the console. It does not appear the the `h1` but there is not any code to replace the text content of the `h1`.